# Invoke the editor in the interactive mode

Tags: python, ipython

When open an editor within Ipython, I usually issue commands

```
In [13]: subprocess.run('vim Person.py', shell=True)
Out[13]: CompletedProcess(args='vim Person.py', returncode=0)
```

How to do it in a straight-forwards method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`%edit` magic command](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#magic-edit) is the canonical way offered by IPython. It invokes an editor specified by `$EDITOR`, optionally loading a specified file, and executes the code after it's closed.

Another common workflow is to have editor and console open in different windows and copy-paste between the two (the `%paste` magic is handy here).

[Jupyter Notebook](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebook.html) seems to offer experience similar to MATLAB console though I don't have any experience with it.