# Fetch content of file to an interactive console

Tags: python

The conventional way to copy content from a file to the Ipython console is:

```
In [33]: subprocess.run("pbcopy < script.py", shell=True)
Out[33]: CompletedProcess(args='pbcopy < Person.py', returncode=0)
```

How to get it done directly with magic  % symbol.

Comment: [Deja vu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50441346/invoke-the-editor-in-the-interactive-mode/50443101#50443101)

Comment: That said, that answer probably qualifies as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invoke the editor in the interactive mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50441346/invoke-the-editor-in-the-interactive-mode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in IPython, you can execute a shell command by just prepending `!` to the line.

Then, there's the `%paste` magic which is supposed to paste from the clipboard in environments that have it (it's present in Windows, dunno about other OSes).